In C++, How can I do some operations before default destructor of every derived class?or call destructor of base class first?
In C++, How can I do some operations before default destructor of every derived class?or call destructor of base class first?
I set the base class destructor as a pure virtual function, but this does not enforce the subclass to override the destructor. Therefore, I want to perform some operations before the default destructor is called in cases where some subclasses do not implement the destructor, or execute the base class destructor first before the subclass destructor.
class A
{
    public:
        ~A() 
        { 
            std::lock_guard<std:: mutex> guard(m_lock);
            setDisable(); 
        }
};
class B: public A
{
    public:
    // before call ~B() I need to call B::setDisable() to notify other thread
    // do not use resource of this object of class B
    ~B(); 
};


I set the base class destructor as a pure virtual function, but this does not enforce the subclass to override the destructor. It is not thread-safe that if subclass do not override the destructor instead of using default destructor.

You have not set the base destructor as pure virtual.  In fact, you have not declared it virtual at all.  Had you done so, the ~B destructor would handle it all and ~A wouldn't be involved.

It's not the best design to encode logic at the time of destruction to say "don't use me", especially when you have a class hierarchy.

The only way is to have some wrapper around every A that enforces this.  It's not possible do to it directly in A for the exact reason your diagram outlines.

Relevant thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646427/should-destructors-be-threadsafe

You say "I set the base class destructor as a pure virtual function," but in your code, ~A() is not a pure virtual function. Please edit your question to clarify

Possibly related to (or a duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844137/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-c-class-to-automatically-execute-a-method-just-before

C++ rules don't allow a base class destructor to run before the derived class destructor; that's just the way it is.  This is enforced so that the destructor always starts with the object in a valid state.

XY problem

There is no way to automatically call a function before an arbitrary class destructor. But you can create a proxy class that would be used instead. Make your proxy class derived form the actual class that contains implementation and its destructor will be called first. Making destructors protected will prevent the objects from being used without proxy.
Here is an example using your classes:
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    bool _disabled = false;
    public:
        A() { std::cout << "A::A\n"; }
        auto setDisable() { _disabled = true; std::cout << "set disabled\n"; }
        protected: virtual ~A() = 0;
};

A::~A()  { std::cout << "~A\n"; if(!_disabled) abort(); }

class B: public A
{
    public:
    B() { std::cout << "B::B\n"; }
    auto do_some_job() { std::cout << "B doing job\n"; }

    // before call ~B() I need to call B::setDisable() to notify other thread
    // do not use resource of this object of class B
    protected: virtual ~B() override 
    { 
        std::cout << "~B\n";
    }
};

template<class T>
struct proxy : T
{
    using T::T;
    virtual ~proxy() { std::cout << "~proxy\n"; this->setDisable(); }
};

int main()
{
    auto b = new proxy<B>;
    b->do_some_job();
    delete b;
}

Executing this code you will get:
A::A
B::B
B doing job
~proxy
set disabled
~B
~A

